# std::logic_error instead of return false

Tags: c++, exception, validation

I am looking for someones opinion about the usage of `std::logic_error` instead of using a complicated list of nested if/elseif return true/false.

I would like to move from a lot of similar function like the one below

```
bool validate_data(){
    std::vector<int> v; 
    //fill with data
    if( v.find(10) == v.end() ){
       return false;
    } 
    // other checks that return false
}
```

to

```
bool validate_data(){
    std::vector<int> v; 
    //fill with data
    if( v.find(10) == v.end() ){
       throw std::logic_error("error message");
    } 
    // other checks that return false
}
```

and call all this list of functions in a single `try-catch` block.

Since it is a derived from `std::exception` probably I don't know if it is a good idea.

Is anyone using like the example below?

Thanks a lot

AFG

Comment: You will have same complicated if/elseif code with `throw` instead of `return`. What is the advantage?

Comment: @Tadeusz: since everything boild up in a single validation failure I can write less complicated code i.e. just a list of calls to these validation functions in a single try/catch clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should only use exceptions for exceptional circumstances. Using (and checking) return values is far more efficient when the chances of it being true or false are non-trivial. Exceptions are more efficient only when the chance of throwing is so small as to out-weigh the cost of the return-value check.

So if the chances of invalid data are very very low, then go with exceptions. Otherwise, the current solution should not only be fine, but slightly more efficient as well (As throwing and handling is relatively expensive).

Comment: Hi Dennis!Tanks for the response (coming after a bit). Few times after I  went through these dilemma I also would say that with exception it must come also 'exception-safety' techniques. Without it I found my programs 'Incomplete' and not really safe. I now use boost scope exit for that. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Only use exceptions for exceptional situations.

Is not finding the value 10 an exceptional situation?  Or is it just a normal situation?

Renaming your method from validate_data to is_data_valid makes it much clearer.  If the method returns true, it's valid.  If it returns false, it isn't.  No need to use exceptions for this.

Comment: The documentation of std::logic_error  says "The class serves as the base class for all exceptions thrown to report errors presumably detectable before the program executes, such as violations of logical preconditions". COuld it mean that I can use it instead of assertion? That might enforce also what are you saying about valid/invalid vs exceptional cases.

Comment: If the violation of the logical precondition means that there's an error in your application, use an assert.  If the violation means that the user has given incorrect input, just report the error to the user.  Regarding exceptions, I would only use exceptions if you are sure that you handle it consistently in your application.  This means that ALL of your methods can handle being stopped in the middle of the execution.  In my case, I still have lots of code in plain C, so I don't like adding exceptions in my application.

Answer (score 3):

Since your function is called `validate_data()` I'd only throw an exception if there is any internal error within the function and use `true` or `false` to indicate that the function did validate the input, but it was either `valid` (`return true`) or invalid (`return false`).

This will not prevent you from having multiple `if() else if() else` constructs but it will make the code cleaner and easier to distinguish if the data were invalid or an internal error happened.

```
try {
  bool valid = validate_data(foo);
  /* process data or break if invalid */
} catch (std::exception &ex) {
  /* internal error happened */
}
```

as you can see it will make your code longer, IMHO cleaner.